# SQLAlchemy 1.4 table query that includes first result of second table

Tags: sqlalchemy

Good day,

I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4 and have two tables, one is a table for `Widget` and the second is an `Image` table. Currently, I query for the widget then once found I query for the most recent image for that given widget so I return an API response that includes the widget information plus one image of the widget.

As a simple optimization step I added a cache when fetching the single image of each widget but that was only a temporary stop-gap and I know there must be a way to load the most recent image of the widget at the same time I request the widget.

I found some examples of using `.scalar_subquery()` which I believe can fit my needs but the examples were a bit shallow in context and I didn't manage to apply the patterns from those examples to my code base.

Here is what my `get_by_id` method looks like for reference. `self_table` is the `Widget` ORM table.

```py
async def _get_one(self, item_id: UUID):
        query = (
            select(self._table)
            .options(selectinload(self._table.things))
            .where(self._table.id == item_id)
        )
        try:
            item = (await self._db_session.execute(query)).scalar_one()
        except NoResultFound:
            item = None
        return item
```

Where `things` are a many to many table that I load with the widget so I don't make two SQL calls for each widget API request. Adding `things` to the widget like this is easy since I load all `things` on the many-to-many relationship without any constraints. But as described above, I do want to constrain the images I load and this is where I have found it difficult.

Ideally, I would fetch the most recent image from the Image table which has a foreign key on the widget ID and if more images are needed then the user can fetch all images of the widget to load them separately.

---

Alternatively, I could add an `image_id` column to the `Widget` table then with zero extra work return the `Widget` item and allow the client to fetch the the Image if they have not already cached the Image already. Not sure if this is more common approach or not. Making a query for both the widget and image in each endpoint or for various points of the app has me handling both objects which is not really ideal either.

So maybe I have my ideal solution wrong and really there may be a way to define a `sa.relationship` that only returns the first Image row whenever I query for a `Widget`?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do want to add that the linked question is a duplicate of my question but later I changed my requirements and only wanted the ID of the child table which lead me to using a simple `column_property`. So for others that may a solution for them.